# What is the materials science behind thermal diffusion in multispectral camouflage?

Tags: materials, chemical-formula

I've been interested in infrared and near-infrared camouflage (called multispectral camouflage) for a couple of days now, and [I've found a video or two](https://youtu.be/MGjmy3pbNEM) of certain companies that have created fabrics that both reject outside thermal and near-infrared radiation, and allow for scattering of infrared and near-infrared radiation originating from the body as body heat.

It's been three days and I've been searching for the materials science behind the camouflages, but I can't find anything relevant.

So, what materials/substances do you think they are using for this type of camouflage and why?

Comment: What do you mean by "reject" and "scattering"? Is the aim for a body to appear black when illuminated  by an IR lamp? And you can only scatter outside light. Thermal emission always occurs in all directions anyway.

Comment: The aim is both to take incoming thermal (IR) radiation, and thermal energy from body heat, and when the material radiates the IR energy it sends it off into arbitrary directions, not just toward the observer, lowering absorbed heat by the observer. In this sense the external heat (for instance from an IR lamp) is not very reflected by the material; it should appear like normal background when illuminated, but also take internal body heat and "diffuse" it in all different directions, again, giving out  a heat signature that is similar or equal to the background.

Comment: You seem to be missing the point. Except polished metal, hardly any material reflects (like a mirror) IR. And any warm body, including a piece of camouflage, radiates thermal IR into all directions. You can add an insulation layer on the inside to keep your body heat, but I think that´s not the idea here.

Comment: The wiki article suggests that Peltier devices are used to spatially modulate the thermal output across an object to break up an infrared image. Is that kind of what you mean?

Comment: What would make sense is a material that *absorbs* NIR (making it look black in an IR searchlight), and does not absorb FIR, because a low absorbance generally means a low emittance at the same wavelenght. Could that be it?

Comment: No in the video they have a graphic showing incoming IR radiation being deflected and emitted (body heat) IR radiation being sent in arbitrary directions. The video also clearly shows the fabric is thin and flexible, so I doubt physical peltier plates would be involved. What I'm thinking is one of two things; one, that they made a fiber or coating that scatters IR energy, or two, a fiber or coating exhibits the Peltier effect; using up the body heat to produce electric current to drive a peltier cooler. Any thoughts?

Comment: New development; Rayleigh scattering. Do you think they found a material that scatters infrared radiation?